# What the value (not set) means in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

[image]

when I select the city in GA its showing "not set" can you please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

(not set) is a placeholder name that Analytics uses when it hasn't received any information for the dimension you have selected. The reasons for (not set) appearing as a dimension value vary according to the report.